# Fatal error: Class 'PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception' not found in C:\wamp\www\Scaffolding\PHPMailer-master\src\PHPMailer.php on line 1943

Tags: php, html

I've been trying to set up an smtp mailer so that once a user fills in a form on my website it will automatically send the message via email to me. I have all the files of PHPmailer in the same directory but it keeps on giving me the above error whenever the form is submitted.

This is line 1943 of PHPmailer.php :

```
throw new Exception($this->lang('authenticate'));
```

Does anyone know what the problem is ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't imported the class into your namespace.

If you don't do that, it will expect the class to have the namespace. It doesn't.

There are two solutions. Add a use statement, or give the fully qualified class name:

```
<?php

namespace Random;

use Exception;

class Whatever
{
    public function whatever()
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

Or, using a fully qualified class name:

```
<?php

namespace Random;

class Whatever
{
    public function whatever()
    {
        throw new \Exception();
    }
}
```

I prefer the first option. Some classes have long fully qualified names, so it's easier to say `use Ridiculously\Long\Fully\Qualified\ClassName;` and then just referring to `ClassName` in your code. Otherwise you'd need to say `new \Ridiculously\Long\Fully\Qualified\ClassName()`, which sucks.

The other advantage with the first way is, you can see instantly every class used in your code.

Comment: There is already a name space included in another file called exception.php as below :

    namespace PHPMailer\PHPMailer;


    class Exception extends \Exception
    {
   
        public function errorMessage()
        {
           return '<strong>' . htmlspecialchars($this->getMessage()) . "</strong><br />\n";
        }
    }

can i just put require 'exception.php'; at the top of the file ?

Comment: Are you using a class autoloader, like composer?

Comment: no, should i ? For the time being i am just requiring the files as below:

require("PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php");
 require("PHPMailer-master/src/SMTP.php");

Comment: then you need to require every class, including the exceptions and every other class that PHPMailer might use. See my other answer regarding autoloading. It's the way forward!!

Comment: ok will do, do i need the 6.0 as thats not the version i have ?

Comment: I just looked in packagist.org (where you find all the cool libraries) for the latest major version. Feel free to choose another. Have look here https://packagist.org/packages/phpmailer/phpmailer

Comment: Hi Again, I solved the problem regards the phpmailer files etc. Now I have a problem with regards sending the mail, I am getting this error : SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful . Login is correct and server details also, do you know what it might be ?

Comment: possibly server certificate verification?

Answer (score 0):

either change the code to: `throw new \Exception($this->lang('authenticate'));`
or add 
`use Exception;` to the top of the file.

The problem is the file you are editing is in the `namespace PHPMailer\PHPMailer;` which means when you throw Exception it expects the class to be in the same namespace.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your error could be that your classes are not being autoloaded.

With PSR compliant autoloading, you no longer need to `require_once` every class file that you need. Everyone uses Composer to achieve that these days. https://getcomposer.org/

To start using Composer in your project once installed, all you need is a `composer.json` file. This file describes the dependencies of your project and may contain other metadata as well.

```
{
  "require": {
    "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^6.0"
  }
}
```

`composer install` installs PHPMailer into a vendor folder.

In your app's index.php, just add  `require_once 'vendor/autoload.php;`

Now all classes will load without the need to require them in, and your error should vanish!

Comment: "*Everyone uses Composer*". Not everyone who cares about server security and integrity in large production environments. I always go out of my way to make a clean autoloader just so I don't have to deal with the crap that is `composer`.

Comment: You should never run composer executable on production. It shouldn't even be installed. You use composer to require in the libraries you use, locally, and you copy those files over to the server. Then you only call the autoloader. So I don't see any weight to your points of 'security and integrity'.